# Teachable Machine and p5.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, p5.js, ml5.js, teachable-machine

I'm trying to import my teachable machine model to my p5.js sketch.

Current Problem: After I flipped the video input to mirror the camera, there's a mismatch of position of the dots and the position of my face is at. Below is the snippets of code that I used to draw circle on the exact position of my face.

```
  push();
  textSize(8);
  if (poser) { //did we get a skeleton yet;
    for (var i = 0; i < poser.length; i++) {
      let x = poser[i].position.x;
      let y = poser[i].position.y;
      ellipse(x, y, 5, 5);
      text(poser[i].part, x + 4, y);
    }
  }
  pop();
```

This is the what it currently look like:
[image]

Here's the link to the full sketch:  https://editor.p5js.org/wangz318/sketches/tdJm565Ap
and in case the link goes down:

```js
const modelURL = 'https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/models/kWOrQ14vz/';
// the json file (model topology) has a reference to the bin file (model weights)
const checkpointURL = modelURL + "model.json";
// the metatadata json file contains the text labels of your model and additional information
const metadataURL = modelURL + "metadata.json";


const flip = true; // whether to flip the webcam

let model;
let totalClasses;
let myCanvas;

let classification = "None Yet";
let probability = "100";
let poser;
let video;
let flippedVideo;

// A function that loads the model from the checkpoint
async function load() {
  model = await tmPose.load(checkpointURL, metadataURL);
  totalClasses = model.getTotalClasses();
  console.log("Number of classes, ", totalClasses);
}


async function setup() {
  myCanvas = createCanvas(400, 400);
  // Call the load function, wait until it finishes loading
  videoCanvas = createCanvas(320, 240)

  await load();
  video = createCapture(VIDEO, videoReady);
  video.size(320, 240);
  video.hide();

}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  if(video) {
    flippedVideo = ml5.flipImage(video);
    image(flippedVideo,0,0,video.width,video.height);
  }
  fill(255,0,0)
  textSize(18);
  text("Result:" + classification, 10, 40);

  text("Probability:" + probability, 10, 20)
  ///ALEX insert if statement here testing classification against apppropriate part of array for this time in your video

  push();
  textSize(8);
  if (poser) { //did we get a skeleton yet;
    for (var i = 0; i < poser.length; i++) {
      let x = poser[i].position.x;
      let y = poser[i].position.y;
      ellipse(x, y, 5, 5);
      text(poser[i].part, x + 4, y);
    }
  }
  pop();
  
  
}

function videoReady() {
  console.log("Video Ready");
  predict();
}


async function predict() {
  // Prediction #1: run input through posenet
  // predict can take in an image, video or canvas html element
  const {
    pose,
    posenetOutput
  } = await model.estimatePose(
    flippedVideo.elt //webcam.canvas,
  );
  // Prediction 2: run input through teachable machine assification model
  const prediction = await model.predict(
    posenetOutput,
    totalClasses
  );

  // console.log(prediction);
  
  // Sort prediction array by probability
  // So the first classname will have the highest probability
  const sortedPrediction = prediction.sort((a, b) => -a.probability + b.probability);

  //communicate these values back to draw function with global variables
  classification = sortedPrediction[0].className;
  probability = sortedPrediction[0].probability.toFixed(2);
  if (pose) poser = pose.keypoints; // is there a skeleton
  predict();
}
```

Anyone know how to get it right?

My goal: Get the flipping, and the facial position dots position right at the same time.
https://editor.p5js.org/wangz318/sketches/tdJm565Ap

Comment: Hi and welcome! Your question is a bit ambiguos in it's current form. By flipping do you mean flipping the camera image and the goal being getting the facial points to be overlaid in the correct place on top of the flipped image ? (If so, it appears the p5.js sketch you shared in the link above already does this)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code snippet as well as the image: very useful! While your code works just fine on my PC laptop, the fact that circles appear to the right and lower makes me think maybe you're running this on a Mac with Retina display (or a PC with higher pixel density) which potentially would scale some of the content twice. Can you try adding `pixelDensity(1)` in `setup()` and try again ? (For more info see [pixelDensity](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pixelDensity) and [displayDensity](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/displayDensity))...

Comment: ...If calling `displayDensity()` in `setup()` returns `1` there could be another underlying issue. Setting a breakpoint via browser Developer Tools and stepping through should help pin point where the calculation changes unepectedly. My guess is the x,y offset is always the same when this happens in which case a hacky workaround might be using [`map()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/map) to remap the coordinates to a range that appears correct. (This will be a manual process though: ideally debugging will reveal the true source of the issue here). Hope this helps.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thank you George! I tried adding `pixelDensity(1)` in `setup()` and now the dots are mapped correctly! But the text `(poser[i].part, x + 4, y);` that I used to indicate the facial feature names are still not mirrored correctly. (e.g: it still shows the "left eyes" on my right eyes). Do you know why is that?

Comment: That's great news! You can try flipping the x coordinate by subtracting the x from width. Try `let x = video.x - poser[i].position.x;` Good luck

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza actually I tried that before but if so, the text's position would be are completely flipped and no longer map to  the exact position of my face if that makes sense

Comment: Oooops, my mistake. You're right! The labels *should* appear as expected, since you're passing `flippedVideo` to posenet. The [issue is posenet outputs flipped labels](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/493). A hacky workaround (until it gets fixed) is to manually replace strings: ```let partName = poser[i].part;
      let partNameSwapped = partName;
      if(partName.indexOf('left') >= 0) partNameSwapped = partName.replace('left', 'right');
      if(partName.indexOf('right') >= 0) partNameSwapped = partName.replace('right', 'left');
      text(partNameSwapped, x, y);```

Comment: I've read you're code more carefully and have a better understanding of what's going on: you're using ml5 simply as a utility to flip the webcam image. While ml5 support PoseNet directly, you're inferring the pose and pose classification using Teachable Machine, therefore you should tell your TM model to flip horizontally. You can do that by passing `true` as the second argument to [`estimatePose(yourSampleImage, flipHorizontal)`](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/teachablemachine-community/tree/master/libraries/pose#posenet-model---estimatepose)...

Comment: ...because you're using ml5 to flip the image to render in p5 you need to pass the original(unflipped) image to TeachableMachine. e.g. swap `const { pose, posenetOutput } = await model.estimatePose(
    flippedVideo.elt //webcam.canvas,
  );`  for `const { pose, posenetOutput } = await model.estimatePose(
     video.elt, true
  );`. This is the more elegant solution as opposed to the string replacement hack above.

Comment: Now I understand! Thank you so much for helping!! @GeorgeProfenza